# How to set width cell in the table MS Word using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I want to set the width only on the fifth cell in the table using this code:

```
row_width = {0: 5,1: 25,2: 25}
for set_rows in range(len(all_rows)):
    table.cell(5, set_rows).width = Cm(row_width[set_rows])
```

But, it gives change to all rows in columns.

Can `python-docx` set width only specific rows that we want?

[image: test]

Thank you.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Writing the code is very long, to produce results like in the picture, because my code not using the loop, manually hardcode. I think it will take up space. The essence of the problem is only the use of width in certain cells not for all tables.

Comment: you don't have to copy all your code. just the part necessary for us to recreate the problem. In your case: creation of a word doc with a single table for example.